# How to simplify http.get() with or without params

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-httpclient

```
getPosts(userId?: string): Observable<any> {
  if (userId) {
    const params = new HttpParams().set('userId', userId.toString());
    return this.http.get(ApiUrl + ApiPath, { params }) 
  else {
    return this.http.get(ApiUrl + ApiPath);
  }
}
```

I am trying to combine two `http.get` methods instead of using if and else. Basically, if the userId is defined, create a query param and send it to the API, else, don't include the param.

I have tried using ternary operation but this one does not work as well:

```
this.http.get(ApiUrl + ApiPath, userId ? { params } : null)
```

When I check the RequestUrl in the inspector I see the request as like this: "api/Post?userId="

Comment: One approach would be to create the params empty (`let params = new HttpParams();`), then have `if (userId) { params = params.set('userId', userId.toString()); }`. That's easier to expand to other conditional parameters later. But I wouldn't expect the ternary you show to lead to `?userId=` - if the `null` value is used, that key isn't available in the request.

Comment: Thank you but I have already tried that and i still get the userId in the request url. I am still investigating it.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, I appreciate your interest in refactoring the code.

This can be refactored to

```
  getPosts(userId?: string): Observable<any> {
      if (userId) {
        const params = new HttpParams().set('userId', userId.toString());
        return this.http.get(ApiUrl + ApiPath, { params })
      } 
      return this.http.get(ApiUrl + ApiPath);
    }
```

You don't need else block because the return statement does not execute the lines below.

You can also do it without if condition like below,

```
this.http.get(ApiUrl + ApiPath, userId ? { params } : {})
```

Hopefully, this resolves your issue. Cheers!